# How to create a two node cluster for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: torque

I have 2 PCs running Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop version connected via 1 Gigabit Ethernet switch. I would like to create a 2 node cluster and configure Torque to submit and schedule jobs on the two nodes.

Please note that I am not interested in running MPI type jobs across the nodes. My calculations would be run on one node at at time, but rather than wait and manually submit a new job when a job is finished, I would like to submit multiple jobs using qsub and have them queued until a node is freed up.

I guess my question could be divided into two parts

a) What is the best cluster setup for the system I have described in the above?

b) How do I setup Torque after setting up the cluster. Please note that I have already installed Torque on each machine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be that hard to set up torque for this, you need:

- `torque-server`, `torque-scheduler` and `torque-client` installed in one of the computers;
- `torque-client` installed on the second one;
- Make sure that you are using hostnames and that hostnames can be easily resolved in your network (IPs are not used), force it in to your `/etc/hosts` file if needed;
- For password less access you need to set up ssh keys between the computers;
- A shared NFS home for your user, or another directory that you can use between computers is highly recommended (its good if torque can write the output of the jobs you are sending without any issues);
- Setup the initial torque configuration by editing `/etc/torque/server_name` and `/var/spool/torque/server_priv/nodes`;
- Set up a queue in torque in torque with each of the computers in your network and the resources that are available in each computer (CPUs, RAM).

After that is done the only thing you need to do actually is send jobs to the queue and torque will figure out if there is anything available on your queue.

<sup>**Note:** If you are stuck in any step here please use the search functions on this site to look for how-tos about that subject and if you are stuck on a specific issue with setting up torque just open a new question with "how do I do X in torque". Your question is very vague so the only answer you can get is also very vague...</sup>